# Unable to send email from linux websphere liberty server

Tags: smtp

We have a linux server say X.
From this server how can I check if SMTP is enabled or not.

I tried sending email to my mailbox using below command but email didn't receive.

```
echo "Body of the mail." | mail -s "Testing from the server" abcd.efg@test.co.in
```

Comment: You don't enable smtp on the sending side; if you can reach an email server that accepts your email you can send email. Or if you run one locally, which seems to be the case here. That server may still be retrying your email until it gives up in a few days. It will then bounce the email, and you may or may not see the bounce email, depending on how you configured the server. Check what email server you have installed, and where it puts its log files, that should give you an indication as to what happened to your email. That said, the question is off-topic as it's not about programming.

Comment: When you want to send mail from app deployed on Liberty you use JavaMail API and MailSession object, not `mail` executable.